# Create the appropriate space for variable axis labels

Tags: d3.js

I have two arrays of strings: these two arrays contain the labels that are to be inserted on the `x` and `y` axis (these labels will be those of a heatmap).
`nutsNames` corresponds to the `x` axis (left to right) and the `yearsNames` corresponds to the `y` axis (top to bottom).

As the data may vary, I would like to create a way that fits the data.
So the problem is the positioning of the elements on the axes and the `svg` size.

What I would like to get is something like this:

[image]

The image shows two examples of different data.
(I don't want to show axes, I put them only to understand what is their direction).

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pTGMn2y2KbmyX3qGuAe1?preview).

I thought about finding the longest string in `nutsNames` and multiplying it by a constant (which I don't know how to define) to create the minimum necessary width of the `svg`.

A similar thing I did it for years.

Obviously the code doesn't work.

Comment: So you want to dynamically alter the width and height of the `svg` based on your axis labels?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you can do is input some dummy numbers for the `width`,`height` and `margins` and let it draw the elements first. Now since all your axis labels are in a `g` , you can get the `width` of `g`s for `x` and `y` labels.

The `group<g>` tag wraps the contents inside it so getting its `width/height` will automatically give you the `width/height` of the largest `text` inside it.

Now you have the `width` and `height` of those `g`s, all that's left is to change the dimensions of the `svg` accordingly.

Try adding or removing labels in your data. Here's your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1oYPhkMSa8FCG4GeQvBG?preview&p=preview)